# Write Header first to csv and then append respective column data

Tags: powershell

i am trying to create a csv with the below data here. but not getting and idea on this

New_Extracted_Data is an array:

```
timestamp  _ldmodels_MIN _ldmodels_MAX _ldmodels_AVERAGE
---------  ------------- ------------- -----------------
1599136260 73896.68      73896.68      73896.68         
1599136320 73896.68      73896.68      73896.68         
1599136380 73896.68      73896.68      73896.68
```

1. Below is the way i am planning to write the header, headers are the noteproperty, not getting as header in the array

```
 $GetMembers = $New_Extracted_Data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
            foreach($Member in $GetMembers)
             {
                $All_Columns += $Member.Name + ","
             }

             $All_Columns | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Script\Final_Data.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

and then i am calculating the sum of columns for each membertype

```
                       foreach($Member in $GetMembers)
                            {
                                $Col = $Member.Name
                                if($Col -ne "timestamp")
                                {                                
                                   $Sum_Col = ($New_Extracted_Data | Measure-Object $Col -Sum).Sum                                
                                }
                             }
```

Now i need to write it to csv. below is the expected o/p
e.g.

```
_ldmodels_MIN _ldmodels_MAX _ldmodels_AVERAGE
------------- ------------- -----------------
 221690.04      221690.04      221690.04
```

Please need idea on how to do this. also if there is any issue with my approach let me know.

Comment: There is no need to loop. Just use `-join` --> `$GetMembers.Name -join ','`. Why do it this way at all?

Comment: Why not just `$New_Extracted_Data |Export-Csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring just simply wanting a theoretical explanation, there isn't a practical application for your requirements in the given example. `Export-Csv` can serialize your PowerShell objects into CSV format. `Select-Object` can be used to filter which properties are sent to `Export-Csv`.

```
# Export Your Object to CSV with all custom properties as columns
$New_Extracted_Data | Export-Csv "C:\Script\Final_Data.csv" -NoType

# Export object to CSV without timestamp property
$New_Extracted_Data | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty timestamp |
    Export-Csv "C:\Script\Final_Data.csv" -NoType

# Creating sums of your values when properties are known
[pscustomobject]@{
    _ldmodels_MIN = ($New_Extracted_Data._ldmodels_MIN | Measure -Sum).Sum
    _ldmodels_MAX = ($New_Extracted_Data._ldmodels_MAX | Measure -Sum).Sum
    _ldmodels_AVERAGE = ($New_Extracted_Data._ldmodels_AVERAGE | Measure -Sum).Sum
} | Export-Csv sums.csv -NoType

# Summing all properties except timestamp
$Properties = ($New_Extracted_Data[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Where Name -ne 'timestamp').Name
$Hash = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
    $Hash[$Property] = ($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum
}
[pscustomobject]$Hash | Export-Csv sum.csv -NoType
```